# Angular2 Map "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: angular

So i just started learning Angular2 and im trying to get the data i have on my database and display it on my indexpage but everytime i try to do so i get an error saying "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and i have no idea why i have been searching for hours. Can someone please help me out.

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Bootcamp } from './Bootcamp';

const BOOTCAMP: Bootcamp[] = [];

@Injectable()

export class Bootcamptest {
    private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:54220/Bootcampdata';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAll(): Observable<Bootcamp[]> {
        let bootcamp$ = this.http
            .get(`${this.baseUrl}/GetAlleBootcamps`, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map(mapBootcamps)
            .catch(handleError);

        return bootcamp$;
    }

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');  
        return headers;
    }
}

function mapBootcamps(response: Response): Bootcamp[] {
    // uncomment to simulate error:
    // throw new Error('ups! Force choke!');

    // The response of the API has a results
    // property with the actual results

    return response.json().results.map(toBootcamp)
} 

function toBootcamp(r: any): Bootcamp {
    let bootcamp = <Bootcamp>({
        id: extractId(r),
        naam: r.name,
        description: r.description,
        begindatum: r.begindatum,
        einddatum: r.einddatum
    });

    console.log('Parsed bootcamp:', bootcamp);
    return bootcamp;
}

// to avoid breaking the rest of our app
// I extract the id from the person url
function extractId(bootcampData: any) {
    let extractedId = bootcampData.url.replace('http://localhost:54220/Bootcampdata/Getallebootcamps', '').replace('/', '');
    return parseInt(extractedId);
}

function mapBootcamp(response: Response): Bootcamp {
    // toBootcamp looks just like in the previous example
    return toBootcamp(response.json());
}

// this could also be a private method of the component class
function handleError(error: any) {
    // log error
    // could be something more sofisticated
    let errorMsg = error.message || `Error met het laden van data!`
    console.error(errorMsg);

    // throw an application level error
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
}
```

The component class

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bootcamp } from './Bootcamp';
import { Bootcamptest } from './Bootcamptest';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-bootcamptest',
    template: `
  <section>
    <section *ngIf="isLoading && !errorMessage">
    Loading our hyperdrives!!! Retrieving data...
    </section>
      <ul>
        <!-- this is the new syntax for ng-repeat -->
        <li *ngFor="let person of people">
            <a>
          {{bootcamp.naam}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <section *ngIf="errorMessage">
        {{errorMessage}}
      </section>
  </section>
  `
})
export class Bootcamplistcomponent implements OnInit {
    bootcamp: Bootcamp[] = [];
    errorMessage: string = '';
    isLoading: boolean = true;

    constructor(private bootcamptest: Bootcamptest) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.bootcamptest
            .getAll()
            .subscribe(
         /* happy path */ p => this.bootcamp = p,
         /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
         /* onComplete */() => this.isLoading = false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the error points? it should give you at least a file or a line where it happens. It seems like it's not from `getAll()` method as it seems good to me...

Comment: Check contents of `response.json()` in `mapBootcamps` function. It seems that there is no `results` property in it

Comment: Seems like `.get('${this.baseUrl}/GetAlleBootcamps', { headers: this.getHeaders() })` is null... As far as there is no `DI` exceptions, its hard to find a problem.

Comment: the content of response.json() is an array with the right data from my database in it so i dont think that is the issue.  When i did a console.log(response.json()) i get to see the right data in it. Could it be that the date format im using is causing an issue?

Comment: This is what the console.log looks like
Array[1]
0
:
Object
Begindatum
:
"/Date(1448146800000)/"
Description
:
"test data"
Einddatum
:
"/Date(1450738800000)/"
IdBootcamp
:
1
Naam
:
"Project1"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zh1fwbzuxhBt23U8oKWk?p=preview) with `angular-in-memory-web-api` backend and everything works.

Comment: And your console.log output does not contains `results` property

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using angular2 can you please tell me what i should do so that the results works?

Comment: Maybe use `return response.json().map(toBootcamp)`?

Comment: Ok that made my debugger go further then before now i get this error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined when i try to do:                  let bootcamp = <Bootcamp>({
        id: extractId(r),
        naam: r.name,
        description: r.description,
        begindatum: r.begindatum,
        einddatum: r.einddatum
    });

Comment: Your code tries to `extractId` from `url` property, but there is no `url` property in bootcampData. But, it contains `id` property already.

Comment: Now i dont get any error but i also dont get any output in my browser

Comment: Ok it worked im retarded didnt change the -ng-For. TY so very much

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I just ran into this issue myself. I'm assuming you were also using the following tutorial:

https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/

I was stuck for a long time until I started to dissect my equivalent of "mapBootcamps". What I found was that the ".results" part of the following line: "return response.json().results.map(toBootcamp)" was returning a value of undefined. Thus, when the ".map(toBootcamp)" method is called, it throws the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

To fix the problem, I simply removed ".results" from the line "return response.json().results.map(toBootcamp)" and it worked!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be coming from your API.

In the `mapBootcamps` you commented that every API response had a `results` property but it seems like sometimes it doesn't.

Your `console.log` showed that you had an `array` of `object`, so results does not exist, it is `null`.

If you change `response.json().results.map(toBootcamp)` to `response.json()[0].results.map(toBootcamp)` it'll work, but I don't think that's what you have to do, you should create a method to handle data as an array, or change the return format of your API to an object.

Comment: When i did it showed that it has an array in it with 1 value and that should be correct since i only have 1 row of dummy data in my database so i dont think that is the issue

Comment: can you please add the result of this `console.log`? Maybe it's just because you try to get results property from the array like if it was an object, so it cant work.

Comment: Array[1]
0
:
Object
Begindatum
:
"/Date(1448146800000)/"
Description
:
"testdata"
Einddatum
:
"/Date(1450738800000)/"
IdBootcamp
:
1
Naam
:
"Project1"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: Could it be that the dateformat is giving me issues here?

Comment: no, the problem is that you use the array as if it was an object but it's an array, so the results property doesn't exist in it. Date format will also be an issue for parsing after that.

Comment: tried response.json()[0].results.map(toBootcamp) and still got the same issue. But i will try to do what you said and try to create a method to handle the data as an array but i dont really know how to do that